# Hot network questions sidebar does not show some favicons in Firefox on a high DPI display

Tags: bug, hot-questions, firefox, rendering

I'm currently on a high-resolution display (1920x1200 @ ~224 PPI), using Firefox 36.0.1 on Windows 8.1 with display (Windows DPI) scaling set to 150%.

This seems to cause favicons to not show up for some sites in the hot network questions list:

[image: Screenshot]

This seems to only affect those favicons more than ~4050px down the sprite image.

This occurs at default FF zoom. Zooming out one step in Firefox causes the missing favicons to appear. Zooming in has no effect.

These icons work correctly in IE, which leads me to believe it's a Firefox-specific bug. Perhaps it should be raised on their bugtracker, which I will look into in the morning, but since this affects SE specifically I'll leave this question here to see if anyone can reproduce, and maybe narrow down the cause or find a workaround.

Comment: Guess those icons better be SVG'ified.

Comment: Possibly due to the usage (or FF implementation of) `backgound-position` (related: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=832524)

Comment: Yeah,  couldn't repro with Chrome.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Would you happen to have a copy of FF you can test? I only have this single HiDPI device.

Comment: Desktop computer Firefox also no repro, don't have on the mobile device.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's interesting. I can reproduce on a clean FF profile. I'm using a tablet running x86 Windows - 1920x1200 in 10.1". This occurred on another identical tablet too. Is your desktop one set to 150% DPI scaling with Win8.1?

Comment: Windows 7, no scaling. (I did try zoom, which often have same effect, but not this time)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The scaling is important. This bug only occurs on a scaled display - and Win7 scaling might behave differently from Win8.1 scaling. I have no issues with unscaled Win7 and Win8.1 machines either (tested the zoom too). Thanks for testing anyway.